# Adding Random Id for each unique value in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the table like

```
ID      RANDOM_ID
1       123
10      456
25      789
1       1112
55      1314
10      1516
```

I want the result to be like :

```
ID      RANDOM_ID
1       123
10      456
25      789
1       123
55      1314
10      456
```

The same ID should have same random_ids. I'm using the update statement to generate the Random_IDs after creating the table.

```
CREATE TABLE [RANDOMID_TABLE]([ID] [int]   NULL, [RANDOM_ID] [int]  NULL)
GO

INSERT INTO [RANDOMID_TABLE] ([ID])          
select distinct ABC_ID from RANDOMID_ABC
GO

 ******** This is the update statement for the RANDOM_ID column in 
 [RANDOMID_TABLE] table ************

UPDATE [RANDOMID_TABLE]
SET  RANDOM_ID = abs(checksum(NewId()) % 1000000)
```

Is there something else that I need to add to the update statement?

Please advise.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: On a side note: Why is the column called ID when it's not a row's ID, but can occur multiple times in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you use `update` for this?  Just generate the values when you insert them:

```
insert into [RANDOMID_TABLE] (ID, RANDOM_ID)          
    select ABC_ID, abs(checksum(NewId()) % 1000000)
    from RANDOMID_ABC
    group by ABC_ID;
```

EDIT:

If your problem is collisions, then fix how you do the assignment.  Just assign a number . . . randomly:

```
insert into [RANDOMID_TABLE] (ID, RANDOM_ID)          
    select ABC_ID, row_number() over (order by newid())
    from RANDOMID_ABC
    group by ABC_ID;
```

This is guaranteed to not return duplicates.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I tried this but the counts don't match. The distinct counts of the ABC_ID, ID and RANDOM_ID should all be the same technically. But when I do this insert or update, the counts only match for ABC_ID and ID. The Random_ID counts do not match to either of those.

Comment: @atulyadharmaraj . . . How large is your data?  The calculation of the random id is likely to generate collisions, once you have more than 10,000 rows it is a real possibility.  At more than 200,000 it is pretty much a certainty.

Comment: oh that makes sense now on why it goes funky after 10,000 lines. My data set is a total of 6753155 lines with 639693 of those as distinct IDs

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff. This solved the collisions issue and got the randomIds as per Ids count. Very helpful trick I've learnt today. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

At a total guess, are you simpling wanting to `UPDATE` the table so that all the values of a specific `ID` to have the same value for `Random_ID`? Like this?

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable (ID int, Random_ID int);
INSERT INTO YourTable
VALUES(1 ,123),
      (10,456),
      (25,789),
      (1 ,1112),
      (55,1314),
      (10,1516);
GO

WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT ID,
           Random_ID,
           MIN(Random_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS Min_Random_ID
    FROM YourTable)
UPDATE CTE
SET Random_ID = Min_Random_ID;

GO

SELECT *
FROM YourTable;
GO

DROP TABLE YourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script you need with use of temporary table (you need it to persist your random results for each unique ID):

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (ID INT, RANDOM_ID INT)
INSERT @Tbl (Id) VALUES(1), (10), (25), (1), (55), (10)
SELECT Id, abs(checksum(NewId()) % 1000000) AS Random_Id INTO #distinctData FROM @Tbl GROUP BY Id
SELECT D.* FROM @Tbl T JOIN #distinctData D ON D.ID = T.ID
DROP TABLE #distinctData
```

Obviously, you don't need the first two rows where I create and initialize data table

Result:

```
Id  Random_Id
1   354317
1   62026
10  532304
10  604768
25  874209
55  718643
```

Answer (score 0):

You want one random value per ID. So one should think that the following would work:

```
with ids as 
(
  select distinct id 
  from randomid_table
)
, ids_with_rnd as 
(
  select id, abs(checksum(NewId()) % 1000000) as rnd
  from ids
)
update randomid_table
set random_id =
(
  select rnd
  from ids_with_rnd
  where ids_with_rnd.id = randomid_table.id
);
```

It doesn't however. SQL Server is somewhat buggy here and still creates different numbers for the same ID.

So, your best bet may be: do your update that does create different values (your original update statement). Then correct the data as follows:

```
update randomid_table
set random_id = 
(
  select min(random_id) 
  from randomid_table rt2
  where rt2.id = randomid_table.id
);
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=504236db66fba0f12dc7e407a51451f8